# Adding many to many data to MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (ingredient, recipe, recipe_ingredient) and a csv file with around 4000 rows of recipes :

```
name, ingredients, time, url,...
Chicken salad, ['chicken', 'lettuce', 'tomato'] ...
```

The ingredients table is already populated with all ingredients, and has a simple schema (id, name).

Is there an easy way of finding the corresponding ingredient id from its name, and adding the relevant recipe id along with all ingredient ids to recipe_ingredient?

Comment: If the names of the ingredients are supposed to be unique, you can get rid of the `id` and use only the `name` as PK. It will save many `JOIN`s

Comment: I'm  not see solution without coding

Comment: We need your Relational Schema my friend, your column names, PK, FK and etc...